# Clojure - how to use my personal debug library in multiple projects?

Tags: maven, clojure, dependencies, leiningen

I have a `mascip.debug` library with a few functions that I like to use everywhere. In each of my projects (only two at the moment - I'm a new Clojurian), I have this library in `src/`.

I would like to put it somewhere in my PATH, and then be able to use it in any project that I write. Is that silly? Possible? Or would you say I absolutely should start using Maven, as [explained here](http://nakkaya.com/2010/03/16/adding-custom-libraries-into-local-leiningen-repository/), so I can declare the dependency in my ~/.lein/profiles.clj file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lein install` puts your library in your ~/.m2/repository, and then you can use it as a dependency from other projects even though you haven't pushed it to a maven repository.

Comment: This is fine, although really you should prefer uploading it to Clojars.

Comment: I have now uploaded to Clojars (see my answer below). It's still good to know how to do this thing locally, I will probably need it in the future.
I'm amazed at how easy everything is, with Leiningen.

Comment: `lein install` is better when you have a dependency on a library that is often modified, whether because you're modifying it, or because you're using recent versions of a development branch of a project.  In that situation, doing an upload to Clojars every time you have a new version is less convenient, and it clutters up Clojars.  Both practices have their place.

Comment: Btw `lein install` will overwrite an existing pom.xml, which may be undesirable if that file has been customized by hand, e.g. because the project uses Maven directly.  You have to be careful to put the file back the way it was in that case.

Comment: Thank you Mars! I have noticed exactly what you say: at the moment I'm modifying that library daily, so `lein install` is better suited. And then Clojar is perfect when I want to share it (with others, and between my own computers).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can create a jar  (use lein jar or lein uberjar)
Then in your project's project.clj you can add
:resource-paths ["src/mascip_debug.jar"]

Answer (score 2):

Diego Basch's answer is exactly what I asked for.

Now, I've realized that sometimes I would like to use this library from a laptop, and found out that deploying to Clojars is SO easy. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/ato/clojars-web/wiki/tutorial), and now I can use my library from anywhere :-)

I imagined it would be harder to use Clojars. All it took was `lein deploy clojars`. Amazing!